# Is there a technique for finding thickness of connected components?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

Say I have a binary image of a human form for instance (white human silhouette on black background). Is there a good way to define minimum thickness? I would say maybe the wrists would be the thinnest part of the connected component as a whole. But it's not obvious to me how to define this. Perhaps the amount of erosion required before producing two or more disconnected components?

So far I have this

```py
from skimage.measure import euler number
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_min_thickness(img: np.ndarray):
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
    n_components_start, _ = cv2.connectedComponents(img, connectivity=4)
    n_components = n_components_start
    euler_4_start = euler_number(img, connectivity=4)
    euler_4 = euler_4_start
    euler_8_start = euler_number(img, connectivity=8)
    euler_8 = euler_8_start
    thickness = 0
    if n_components_start > 0:
        while n_components == n_components_start \
                    and euler_4 == euler_4_start and euler_8 == euler_8_start:
            img = cv2.erode(img, kernel)
            thickness += 2
            n_components, _ = cv2.connectedComponents(img, connectivity=4)
            euler_4 = euler_number(img, connectivity=4)
            euler_8 = euler_number(img, connectivity=8)
    return thickness
```

Comment: Thanks for advising

Comment: A medial axis would provide your required thickness. But not directly, as thin bits towards the ends of the medial axis should not count. This would require a bit of development. But I’m sure it’s been done before.

Comment: Medial axis as in do skeletonization, take the normal to the skeleton at each point and use that as a measuring stick?

Comment: Skeletonization produces an approximation to the medial axis. That's fine. You might be able to find some function that produces the medial axis with the distance to the boundary. The medial axis is formed by points that are at equal distance to at least two boundary points, this distance is the one we're looking for here. You can replicate the same information with a plain old skeletonization and a distance transform, reading the distance transform values at the skeleton pixels.

Comment: Ah I'm with you. Thanks

Comment: [skimage.morphology.medial_axis](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.medial_axis) seems to return both the skeleton and the distance transform.

Comment: Excellent, that does it. Happy to accept your response if you add one. Otherwise I'll get around to it at some point.